# Sending variable client to the server (socket.io)

Tags: javascript, python, html, socket.io

I want to send a variable another than the 'message' to the backend how can I do it ( other variable is named frienddid)
[this is the backend and I have message and frienddid variable coming from clientside I am trying to have frienddid variable but I can't](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjgOi.png)
[This is the clientside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMQHV.png)
[Html part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w03jF.png)

[Things I have tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUckO.png)
[Things I have tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5fkS.png)

Comment: Please post the code as text, not a screenshot.